# Mosquitto - Unable to connect over network other than on the default port

Tags: port, mqtt

I am running Mosquitto 1.4.8 on Ubuntu successfully on port 1883 (tested from another machine with `mosquitto_sub`/`mosquitto_pub`). However I am encountering issues when attempting to use another port eg.

`mosquitto -p 1884 -c moddebug.conf`

This works OK if I access it from the same machine e.g.:

`mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1884`

but if I attempt to connect from another machine I get an error:

```
mosquitto_pub -h IP_ADDRESS -t exmapleTopic -p 1884
Connection timed out
```

My moddebug.conf file is:

```
log_type all
log_dest file mosquitto2_log.log
```

The log does not provide any extra information:

```
Config loaded from mosdebug.conf.
Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1884.
Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1884.
mosquitto version 1.4.8 terminating
```

I have tried altering the firewall rules (but this did not help):

```
ufw allow 1884/tcp
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

Comment: Please enable Mosquitto logging (set `log_type` to `all`); the info in the log may point you in the right direction. If not please edit the question and add the log output (from startup through to after the `mosquitto_pub` call is processed). Also note the comments re `-p` in the [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html).

Comment: Do you have the firewall up?   `ufw status verbose` and see if it is running, and port 1884 is allowed through.  If not, `ufw allow 1884/tcp` will fix it.

Comment: As you say there should be more info in the log; please confirm that `log_type` is set to `all`; showing the `conFIle.conf` in the question would be good (confusing that the log mentions `mosdebug.conf`?). You can also try `mosquitto -v -p 1884 -c conFIle.conf` (the `-v` should override the logging options in the config file). You can also use `-d` with `mosquitto_pub` to get debug info from that. Note that version `1.4.8` is quite old (2016).

Comment: I have rewritten your question to reflect the information provided (it was becoming confusing). Please feel free to reject/correct any misunderstandings. If this is all correct then it looks like this is a networking issue and we would need more info (e.g. are both machines on the same LAN, are you using virtual machines/docker etc). Note that it is important that you provide any error messages you receive when running a command (if you don't note these I would assume there was no error)

Comment: I have installed ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop virutal machine on Windows 10 64x. I have reinstalled mosquitto to newses version. In LAN everything works fine, but when I change network I can't get communication

Comment: @Dursial please update your question and say exactly what you are doing (be very specific and include IP addresses etc). There is a good chance your issue is due to your Hyper-V configuration (the 'Default Switch' is connected to an 'Internal Network' and cannot be accessed from outside the host). A good first step is to ensure you can ping the VM from the machine you are running `mosquitto_pub` on (if you can't then try to resolve that first).